# Google Volley Imageloader - Uncache a 302 redirect request or intercepting the redirect url

Tags: android, redirect, caching, android-volley, http-status-code-302

I have a set url (ex: http://mywebsite.com/cawn28xd/user_avatar) I call for imageloading that redirects to another link that may or may not be different.

> I want to be able to either intercept the 302 redirect and grab the url so the imageloader will not cache that specific url (This brings up the issue the 302 redirect url will be cached, but should be handled on the setShouldCache(false) call for the request)

OR

> I want to be able to invalidate or remove caching from the specified URL using Google Volley and it's imageloader.

I am using the [singleton class provided](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html) from the android developers guide including the default image loading request:

```
RequestEntity.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader().get(mImageURL,
             ImageLoader.getImageListener(mImageView,
             R.drawable.default_avatar, R.drawable.default_avatar));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imageloader provided from android volley uses a cachekey in order to cache requests, but during its process it makes a simple image request.

So just use a request:

```
 Request<Bitmap> imageRequest = new ImageRequest(requestUrl, listener,
  maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_avatar);
     }
  });
imageRequest.setShouldCache(false);
RequestEntity.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue().add(req);
```